How do I swap multiple lists of elements in 1 call?
I'm trying to swap multiple lists of elements using HTMX and Handlebars in 1 call but I cannot find the right solution.
Consider the following page:
<div class="flex-1 space-y-4">
    <h2>Recipes</h2>
    <div class="relative">
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            hx-get="http://localhost:5556/templates/menu/addRecipeList"
            name="search"
            hx-trigger="click,keyup"
            hx-target="#allRecipes"
            class="h-8 px-2 border border-gray-100 rounded shadow-md peer"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="flex-1 space-y-4">
        <ul
            id="allRecipes"
            class="border border-gray-100 rounded shadow-md absolute top-30 left-0 bg-white peer-placeholder-shown:hidden flex flex-col"
        >
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-1 space-y-4">
    <ul
        id="selectedRecipes"
        hx-get="http://localhost:5556/templates/menu/recipes"
        hx-trigger="load"
        hx-target="this"
        class="border border-gray-100 rounded p-4 shadow-md space-y-4"
    >
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="flex-1 space-y-4">
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <ul
        id="ingredients"
        hx-get="http://localhost:5556/templates/menu/ingredients"
        hx-trigger="load"
        hx-target="this"
        class="border border-gray-100 rounded p-4 shadow-md space-y-4"
    >
    </ul>
</div>

It contains 3 things. First, a trivial dropdown list made of an input and a list of items that opens when at least 1 character is typed. There's also a list of recipes, and a list of ingredients containing all the ingredients of the menu.
The dropdown list with recipes to choose gets its html from the backend. It looks like multiple lis like this:
<li>
    <button
        class="px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-50"
        hx-post="http://localhost:5556/templates/menu/1/recipes/2"
        hx-trigger="click"
    >
        recette 2
    </button>
</li>

When clicking the button, a POST call is made to add the clicked recipe to the menu. Also, it updates the recipes and ingredients lists (I wish I could separate these concerns into 3 distinct calls but it does not seem to be the way to do it in HTMX). It does not have a target. Since I want to provide my page with multiple templates in 1 request and hx-target can only provide 1 template to all its targets, I have to use hx-swap-oob, which enables me to target different parts of the page.
This is where I'm stuck.
I tried returning multiple lis with id="recipes" or id="ingredients" and hx-swap-oob="true", but I cannot make it work. For example, when using the beforeend strategy, it only adds items to the existing template, whereas I want the existing html to be replaced. When using the innerHTML strategy, it replaces the existing html, but this applies to each li one by one, which means that each li replaces the one that was just swapped in the html, and in the end I only have the last li displayed.
For example, the ul was like this:
<ul
    id="allRecipes"
    class="border border-gray-100 rounded shadow-md absolute top-30 left-0 bg-white peer-placeholder-shown:hidden flex flex-col"
    hx-swap="innerHTML"
>
</ul>

And the lis were like this:
<li
    id="allRecipes"
    hx-swap-oob="true"
>
    {{ content }}
</li>

I thought about wrapping my lis in an ul, but the problem is that I would have to replace the ul of my page which has some properties such as tailwind classes that I do not want to lose. I could copy paste the classes from the page template to the template that is returned when swapping the recipes/ingredients, but this feels really hacky and uncomfortable, and I fear the technical debt that such workaround would create.
I played with the swap strategies, both on the ul being replaced and on the lis being added, but I could not find a satisfying solution.
I am already uncomfortable having a POST route make an upsert in the database then return 2 different templates all in 1 call, and really start questioning the value of HTMX. I see how it simplifies lots of logic, but I also see how it seems rigid in some situations, which defeats its simplicity.
I would very much appreciate if someone could give me a solution to this problem, that would not be a hacky workaround.

It is unclear (when looking at handlebarsjs.com) why this question is tagged [tag:handlebars.js]

Your question is a LONG story, but it might be duplicate with Can I Reorder a LIst Based On User Provided Values Using Only HTMX?

Can you elaborate on the "innerHTML strategy"? It seems you are missing something there, but I need to know more of your approach to be able to properly assess it.

@Luuk i removed the handlebarjs tag.

@Luuk thanks for the link, I just checked and they are quite similar but not the same. My question deals specifically with swapping multiple items in a div, whereas their question is about swapping 1 div with another div.

@LajosArpad I thought innerHTML would help me replace the content of the ul with the lis, instead of replacing the ul with the lis. In other words I want to keep the ul of the page and replace its content.

@papillon then you have set the innerHTML of the parent of the ul, not the ul instead. Can you edit your question and add the relevant part of the innerHTML-related code there?

@papillon: I looked at it like swapping the multiple items in the div with the same (multiple) items, but in a different order.

@LajosArpad i think we don't understand each other. I have not set the innerHTML of the parent of the ul. I have set the innerHTML of the ul itself. I cannot add a code example now i'll do it as soon as i'm home

@Luuk anyway this is a different question

@papillon I think that once you edit your question, the matter will be clarified and we might be one step from the solution.

@LajosArpad i updated the question with an example

@papillon do you have some Javascript code at play here?

I voted to close, because of "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."  Try to split this LING story into smaller parts, with only (preferably 1) question per part.

@Luuk what do you mean, it's just 1 question: how do i swap multiple lists of elements in 1 call? The "long story" is some context to help understanding the question. It's not multiple questions in 1 post.

@papillon: Ok, than I will stop commenting here, because question does not contain a [mre], it is unclear (to me) where your real problem is, because the LONG story does contain toooo much info  that is not (directly) related to the question.

@Luuk if you don't understand the question just ask some questions or move along instead of wasting the OP time with all sorts of ridiculous assesments. I think my post is quite clear. it contains a question, simplified snippets of my code, some context and examples of what I tried and some relevant insight on my understanding of the library. if that's not enough to you perhaps you need to reassess your level of criticism. the goal is to find a solution to a problem, not to spend the day nitpicking on the form of a post.
